# Apex 5: Admin account is locked

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5

For a long time, I worked on my own workspace. Now I want to create a new workspace, add new users, .... I login into admin account but the account is locked.

[image]

I tried to change password and unlock account.

[image]

After running the @apxchpwd.sql script. I re-login but not successfully. Please help me to unlock and change admin password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's my mistake

I am on APEX 5.0, but you used the apxchpwd.sql of the APEX version that came with RDBMS 12.1.0.2.

I tried again with the 5.0 script and it worked now.